# React-native post method API is not displaying any data after submitting location to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, post

Here is the data which have been showed in `console.log`:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 10,
    "total": 10,
    "_embedded": {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "incubate intuitive experiences",
                "latitude": 51.5033,
                "longitude": -0.1261,
                "slug": "nick.mark.6",
                "phone": null,
                "currency": "USD",
                "hasPic": false,
                "rating": 5,
                "men": 0,
                "isDriverHelpFree": false,
                "hour": 1800,
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

It's from post method API that I have showed in `console.log`.

I am trying to fetch in this way:

```
<View>
    {isLoading ? (<ActivityIndicator />) : (
      responseMsg._embedded && responseMsg._embedded.items ? 
      <Text>Fetch: {responseMsg._embedded.items.latitude}</Text> : 
      <Text>Nothing To Fetch</Text>
    )}
</View>
```

It's not showing anything..
Can someone please help me about this?
I am totally stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `items` is an array, try `responseMsg._embedded.items[0].latitude`(or do something clever with the array index if your request returns more than 1 object). Hope it helps :)

And you also need to chain `.then((response) => response.json())` on your `fetch` to convert the response to an `Object`. Checkout [this docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network#handling-the-response)

Comment: TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined..... it's giving this error

Comment: Thats weird, because you have already check `responseMsg._embedded && responseMsg._embedded.items`. Can you show the complete flow from how you perform the `fetch`, to reading the response in your view?

Comment: if you can come on skype

Comment: You can edit your post to include your code. The code formatting available here is easier to read :)

Comment: Did the `console.log` gives you the result you want? you might have missed the `.then((response) => response.json())` steps, checkout [this docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network#handling-the-response)

Comment: yeah console.log gives me the right result,, oops, let me add that

Comment: Aha, did that help you solve your problem? I have updated my answer so others dont have to go through the comments

Comment: You're welcome. Mind accepting the answer if it helps? Thanks to you too in advanced.